# Spark udf initialization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I want to create a customized regex-based UDF in Spark SQL. My preference would be to create a memory-resident

```
 Map[String,Pattern]
```

Where Pattern refers to a compiled regex version of the string key.  But to do this we need to put the map creation into an "initialize" function of the UDF.

So are there any structures for a Spark udf supporting persistent state across invocations (via Spark SQL) ?

Note that HIVE does support the lifecycle of UDF's. I used that to generated Parse Trees as part of the initialization so that actual invocation of the UDF was against lightning fast trees with no parsing involved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lets start with imports and some dummy data:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import java.util.regex.Pattern

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("foo", "this is bar"), ("foo", "this is foo"),
  ("bar", "foobar"), ("bar", "foo and foo")
)).toDF("type", "value")
```

and map:

```scala
val patterns: Map[String, Pattern] = Seq(("foo", ".*foo.*"), ("bar", ".*bar.*"))
   .map{case (k, v) => (k, new Regex(v).pattern)}
   .toMap
```

Now I see two different options:

- make `patterns` a broadcast variable referenced inside `udf`

  ```scala
  val patternsBd = sc.broadcast(patterns)

  val typeMatchedViaBroadcast = udf((t: String, v: String) =>
    patternsBd.value.get(t).map(m => m.matcher(v).matches))

  df.withColumn("match", typeMatchedViaBroadcast($"type", $"value")).show

  // +----+-----------+-----+
  // |type|      value|match|
  // +----+-----------+-----+
  // | foo|this is bar|false|
  // | foo|this is foo| true|
  // | bar|     foobar| true|
  // | bar|foo and foo|false|
  // +----+-----------+-----+
  ```
- passing map inside closure

  ```scala
  def makeTypeMatchedViaClosure(patterns: Map[String, Pattern]) = udf(
    (t: String, v: String) => patterns.get(t).map(m => m.matcher(v).matches))

  val typeMatchedViaClosure = makeTypeMatchedViaClosure(patterns)

  df.withColumn("match", typeMatchedViaClosure($"type", $"value")).show

  // +----+-----------+-----+
  // |type|      value|match|
  // +----+-----------+-----+
  // | foo|this is bar|false|
  // | foo|this is foo| true|
  // | bar|     foobar| true|
  // | bar|foo and foo|false|
  // +----+-----------+-----+
  ```

Comment: V nice example.  I was thinking along the lines of *registered* Hive UDF's. Closures would not work in that case.  I had neglected to consider that spark udf's must be defined within each SQLContext afresh.

Comment: @zero323: there are relevant differences between the two provided solutions? (I'm mainly interested in performances)